# Using Postgres COMMENTs for tagging tables and fields for auto-discovery

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to tag fields in postgres tables with something similar to [Golang struct tags](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-struct-tags-in-go) to facilitate field discovery for a data ingestion pipeline. With tags, I could query to find tables and columns that support data ingestion.

For example,

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table IS 'Employee Information  json_ingestion:"True"';
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_column IS 'Employee ID number  json_field:"$.person.id"';
```

Are Postgres COMMENTs a good place to store tags for auto discovery?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947405/391445

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, until they aren't.

For example, suppose that at some point you're asked to auto-discover the PII  columns and mask the data they contain, for compliance with applicable regulations (GDPR, etc). You may want to use comments, but comments are already used for another purpose.

That's why SQL Server has Extended Properties instead of a single comment string. Which is not an ideal choice anyway: I like to have a standard `COMMENT` attribute, which is easy to use and remember. But `COMMENT` should only be used for user-readable explanations about what a column is.

So I'd suggest to put any machine-readable information into dedicated tables, and only use the `COMMENT` clause for human-readable documentation.

That said, if you disagree with me about the `COMMENT` clause, your solution is great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like as good a place as any. It's that or a metadata table. The comment is stored in a `text` field in `pg_catalog.pg_description` so it will get compressed/TOASTed if it's large. Be aware that comments can only be set by the object owner or superuser.